# Evaluating shear tensor by gravitational wave

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

The shear tensor is given by:

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\nabla_\alpha U_\beta + \frac{1}{2}\nabla_\beta U_\alpha + \frac{1}{2} U_\alpha U^\mu \nabla_\mu U_\beta + \frac{1}{2} U_\beta U^\mu \nabla_\mu U_\alpha + ...
\end{equation}

and the four velocity U is (1, 0, 0, 0). The covariant derivative is simply $\Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\beta} U_\lambda$. I tried the following.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U_\alpha U^\mu \nabla_\mu U_\beta &= g_{\gamma\alpha}g^{\mu\gamma} U_\mu U^\mu \nabla_\mu U_\beta \\
&= \Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\beta} U_\lambda
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $g_{\gamma\alpha}g^{\mu\gamma}$ becomes $\delta^\mu_\alpha$ and applied to the covariant derivative, $U_\mu U^\mu$ becomes -1. If using this result, the first four terms cancel. However, the answer is simply summing up the free index $\mu$ and the first four terms do not cancel.

The question is why the trick $U_\alpha=g_{\gamma\alpha}g^{\mu\gamma} U_\mu$ is inconsistent with another approach of summing up.

Just to mention the Christoffel symbol not being zero here because of $h_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: In your first equation, free indices in the left are $i,j$ while on the right are $\alpha,\beta$. You have four indices $\mu$ contracted in the first line of your second equation. Please revise your equations.

Comment: The same index can only appear twice. You have an extra $\mu$.

Comment: I see. I did not know the rule on the number of index. Thanks, everyone.